# Is it possible to use common MIME-type for Data URI?

Tags: html, mime-types, data-uri

For example:

```
data:image/*;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudf
```

I worry about cases when an actual MIME-type will be not as expected, such as for `data:image/png` I will get `data:image/jpg` etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data URI is not valid.

Neither [the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) nor [the RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2397) precise anything about a possible `/*` as media subtype, nor any default subtypes, so you'll have to write a full media type.

That is indeed understandable: if a program knows that a file contains an image but don't know whether it's encoded in .jpg, .png or something else, it won't be able to open it. Similarly, browsers won't be able to understand a base-64-encoded image without a subtype parameter.

Depending on your use case, you might wanna use [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-content-type) to infer content type from the raw data directly.

Comment: While you are correct, the docs are actually even more specific: **"A MIME type always has both a type and a subtype, never just one or the other."** [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/MIME_types)

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid.

Some systems, under some circumstances, will perform error recovery (ignoring the content-type you specified and sniffing the data instead). I wouldn't want to depend on that behaviour.